# uppercase letters after periods in dataframe column names

Tags: r, regex

I have an R dataframe with some sports data, and the following column names:

```
 colnames(my_dataframe)
 [1] "id"                               "firstName"                        "lastName"                        
 [4] "position"                         "jerseyNumber"                     "currentTeam.id"                  
 [7] "currentTeam.abbreviation"         "currentRosterStatus"              "height"                          
[10] "weight"                           "birthDate"                        "age"                             
[13] "birthCity"                        "birthCountry"                     "rookie"                          
[16] "handedness.shoots"                "college"                          "twitter"                         
[19] "currentInjury.description"        "currentInjury.playingProbability" "id"                              
[22] "abbreviation"                     "fg2PtAtt"                         "fg3PtAtt"
```

Some column names have periods in them. For those names, I would like to remove the periods, and uppercase the letters after any periods in a column name. For example, column 6 here is `currentTeam.id` and I would like to update this to `currentTeamId`.

```
my_dataframe %>% dplyr::rename_all(. %>% gsub('\\.', '', .))
```

...this simply removes all of the periods in the column names, but does not uppercase the letters after the periods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the [janitor](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor) package. In particular, the `clean_names` function.

```
library(janitor)
data.frame(currentTeam.id = 1:5, 
           currentInjury.playingProbability = 6:10) %>% 
  clean_names(case = "lower_camel")

  currentTeamId currentInjuryPlayingProbability
              1                               6
              2                               7
              3                               8
              4                               9
              5                              10
```

So for your data, try:

```
my_dataframe <- my_dataframe %>%
  clean_names(case = "lower_camel")
```

Comment: i generally accept the base R answer when presented with a good library and good base R example, but here is an exception. clean_names what a convenience. I want to look into the different cases I can pass as a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `sub` to match the `.` followed by a character (captured as a group), and in the replacement, change the case of the backreference (`\\1`)

```
sub("[.](.)", "\\U\\1", names(my_dataframe), perl = TRUE)
# [1] "id"                              "firstName"                      
# [3] "lastName"                        "position"                       
# [5] "jerseyNumber"                    "currentTeamId"                  
# [7] "currentTeamAbbreviation"         "currentRosterStatus"            
# [9] "height"                          "weight"                         
#[11] "birthDate"                       "age"                            
#[13] "birthCity"                       "birthCountry"                   
#[15] "rookie"                          "handednessShoots"               
#[17] "college"                         "twitter"                        
#[19] "currentInjuryDescription"        "currentInjuryPlayingProbability"
#[21] "id"                              "abbreviation"                   
#[23] "fg2PtAtt"                        "fg3PtAtt"
```